# Why sometimes free() : invalid next size (fast) occur and sometimes not?

Tags: c++, free

I wrote this code to solve N-Queens problem.

and sometimes ex) 6 and 10 there are an `error ; free(): invalid next size (fast)` but sometimes like 8 and 2 it isn't

I don't know why it happened in specific case....

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool check(int *a,int num){
  for(int i=0;i<num;++i){
    if((double)(a[i]-a[num])/(i-num)==1.0||(double)(a[i]-a[num])/(i-num)==-1.0||a[i]==a[num])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

int func(int *array,int num,int n){
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    array[num]=i;

    if(num==n-1){
      if(check(array,num))
        sum+= 1;
    }

    if(check(array,num)) sum+=func(array,num+1,n);
  }
  return sum;
}

int main(){
  int N=0;
  cin>>N;
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    int n=0;
    cin >> n;
    int *array=new int[n];
    cout<<"+++++++++"<<n<<endl;
    int a = func(array,0,n);
    delete[] array;
    cout<<a<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009479/yu-hao thank you for your help by editing my sentences

Comment: It means you have a memory corruption bug.

Comment: You code calls `func` with `num == n` which accesses `array` out of bounds when `array[num]=i;` gets called.

Comment: Why are you casting your integers to doubles inside the "check" function? Don't do that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but it did not occur when I remove the sentence    delete[] array;

Comment: Also, put your `if` statements on a separate line from the statements that execute if the expression is true. It's not only easier to read, but easier to debug when going line by line in a debugger.

Comment: Because when you did not bother to `delete` the array, the runtime C library did not detect the completely corrupted memory that resulted from your out of bounds memory access, which resulted in the corrupted heap. Just because your program doesn't crash doesn't mean that it's bug-free. Welcome to C++.

Comment: @selbie i want to detect cases whose gradient is exact one, but if i don't cast integers to doubles, then numbers in between 1 and 2 can be recognized as 1.

Comment: @InhyukCho What did not occur? Do you mean the error wasn't detected? Sure, there's no guarantee that every bug in your code will be detected.

Comment: Undefined behavior means *anything* can happen. Sometimes the error is detected, sometimes your hard drive is erased, sometimes demons fly out of your nose.

Comment: change array to vector and operator [] to at() - it will throw as soon as out-of-bounds access occurs

Comment: ohohohohoh i found the reason.i changed "if(check(array,num)) sum+=func(array,num+1,n);" to "else if(check(array,num)) sum+=func(array,num+1,n);" thank you a lot!

Comment: Rather than trying to do floating point math, your `check` function just needs to check if `△x == △y`.